# How to convert between different point cloud types using PCL?

Tags: ros, pcl, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder whether there is an elegant way to convert instances of `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`  to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>`and vice-versa?

I am trying to load point cloud data from a .pcd-file that only includes XYZ data. Finally, I want to feed this point cloud into a module that requires PointXYZRGB data (but actually does not use the RGB data).

My current solution is to call `pcd::io::loadPCDFile` in order to populate `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` and then just copy points over one-by-one to a XYZRGB point cloud. Note that I am relatively new to C++ programming and might have overseen an obvious solution.

(I am using diamondback)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9515/how-to-convert-between-different-point-cloud-types-using-pcl?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-21

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the meantime, I found the effective (and simple) solution

```
PointCloud<PointXYZ> cloud_xyz;
// [...]
PointCloud<PointXYZRGB> cloud_xyzrgb;
copyPointCloud(cloud_xyz, cloud_xyzrgb);
```

a quick diff on serialized files showed this to be equivalent to

```
cloud_xyzrgb.points.resize(cloud_xyz.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud_xyz.points.size(); i++) {
    cloud_xyzrgb.points[i].x = cloud_xyz.points[i].x;
    cloud_xyzrgb.points[i].y = cloud_xyz.points[i].y;
    cloud_xyzrgb.points[i].z = cloud_xyz.points[i].z;
}
```

See [API documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__io.html#ga9f159e8bddd87efec4e5f5514fbc09d1).

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just saw this showing up on the PCL mailing list by chance. Radu B. Rusu "You need to copy the data manually for now between the two types. [...] Improving this is on the top of our list for PCL 2.x."

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2